# Add a list of groovy files using <lang:groovy>

Tags: spring, groovy, spring-integration, dynamic-languages

I have integrated groovy in my application using [spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/dynamic-language.html). My context looks like:

```
<lang:groovy id="myConfiguration"
                 script-source="classpath:MyGroovy.groovy"
                 refresh-check-delay="1000"/>
```

MyGroovy is an implementation of MyInterface. I was wondering how can I add more files in my classpath (also implementing the same interface) and to have more beans like the one above dynamically?

I would like to get something like:

```
<lang:groovy id="myConfiguration"
                 script-source="classpath:*.groovy"
                 refresh-check-delay="1000"/>
```

And later be able to use a list of implementations of MyInterface and sent it to another bean where I can go through the list and do stuff. My bean would like like:

```
<bean id="myProcessor"
          class="com.package.processor.MyProcessor">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list value-type="com.package.processor.MyInterface">
                <bean class="MyGroovy1"/>
                <bean class="MyGroovy2"/>
                <bean class="MyGroovy3"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Is this possible at all? I have just changed the first part and I already get Exceptions and haven't found in the documentation anything related to this topic.

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'myProcessor': Could not determine
>   scripted object type for GroovyScriptFactory: script source locator
>   [classpath:*.groovy]; nested exception is
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [*.groovy] cannot
>   be opened because it does not exist

Comment: The [spring-integration tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-integration/info) is for the Spring Integration project not generic "integration with Spring" questions.

Comment: I'm really not sure what are You trying to do, but i think You can try to create "myProcessor" bean with list of groovy files(filepaths) and load them inside init-method(). If You would write what is Your goal in it, what are You trying to achive by doing so, maybe i could help some more.
Check out this class : "org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource"

Comment: If I use your approach, then I wouldn't use the lang:groovy tag, which allows me to have objects implementing MyInterface. 
What I am trying to do is to create those implementations dynamically when, matching all the files found by the regex *.groovy